# Open master view from right in Split View Controller iOS8 Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, split, uisplitviewcontroller

I have make **Split View** and it is OK and contain *Master* and *Details* view controller.
Now i wanna open **Master View Controller** from the **Right** side.
I am using Objective C in iOS 8.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ 
    //Figure out that we're on an iPad.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        //Grab a reference to the UISplitViewController
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;


        splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
        //splitViewController.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
//        splitViewController.interfaceOrientation =

        //Grab a reference to the RightViewController and set it as the SVC's delegate.
        RightViewController *rightViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
        splitViewController.delegate = rightViewController;

        //Grab a reference to the LeftViewController and get the first monster in the list.
        UINavigationController *leftNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        LeftViewController *leftViewController = (LeftViewController *)[leftNavController topViewController];
        Monster *firstMonster = [[leftViewController monsters] objectAtIndex:0];





        //Set it as the RightViewController's monster.
        [rightViewController setMonster:firstMonster];

        //Set the RightViewController as the left's delegate.
        leftViewController.delegate = rightViewController;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

please help.

Comment: Hope this one may help you http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/4844/uisplitviewcontroller#t=201609070540261391678

Comment: link not working

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you needs to change `masterview` to left side & `detailsview` to right side. It will not be possible through code as per my knowledge.

Although i found one way through which we can achieve it by do some changes in storyboard.

Initially when you set up `UISplitViewController` you will see it will look like below shown in image. (See connections in red boarder)

[image]

You will see first masterviewcontroller connected with master & Detailviewcontroller with navigation controller.

Now changes the connections to master in place of details & vice versa. Here is the new image after changing it.

[image]

After doing this change if you run code it will show you master page on right side & details page on Left side.

**Important note :**

- If you don't want to follow this steps than alternatively you can consider master page as a detail page & detail page as a master page. And replace codes in both the files that will the second solution to implement this one.

I hope it will guide you.